# Parse a string that don't has decimal point to double

Tags: java

I have a number with precision (9,4) ex:4.0000 //4 but that comes on a string without decimal point (40000). So how on java take that string and convert to 4.0000 in double or Bigdecimal?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question.
Then [edit] your question to include the full source code you have as a [mcve], which can be compiled and tested by others. What do you mean by "comes on a string"? Where is the value `4.0000` is coming from and in what type? What are you trying to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `BigDecimal(BigInteger, int)` constructor. The second argument indicates the scale of the number:

```java
public static BigDecimal convert(String num, int scale) {
    BigInteger bi = new BigInteger(num);
    return new BigDecimal(bi, scale);
}
```

Which you can then call like this:

```java
BigDecimal bd = convert("40000", 4);
System.out.println(bd.toPlainString()); // 4.0000
```